# What are my hosting options for an app that needs tilestashe along side a django app?

Tags: python, web-mapping, server, tilestache

I'm building a GIS webapp that uses [tilestache](http://tilestache.org) to serve MBTiles and a django app to serve geoJson. I'm having trouble understanding exactly what kind of setup I'd need to host this. I'm new to server admin and setup, so something heroku-ish would be nice, but I'd be willing to learn if the solution involved more work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a Linux machine to deploy what you have been working on. I would use nginx as webserver/reverse proxy (because it serves static tiles very fast), the rest (tilestache,django) are very familiar on Linux distro (Ubuntu particularly), you can find many tutorials about deployment of Django + nginx on Google.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I ended up hosted on a single AWS instance with gunicorn workers for tilestache and django proxy_pass'ed through nginx. So far, so good. The site is on my profile if you're interested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Look at Google's AppEngine.  It has django and can serve map tiles up with a little python scripting..